# SSRS how to have bold and normal text in single field

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Is there a way to make a single field in SSRS have half bold and half normal text? Making it 2 fields is not an option.

Thanks
SSRS 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - I'm using SSRS 2005, no option to define an expression on a table cell or textbox.

This is one of the things Crystal Reports has had for decades...

Comment: Thanks thats what I thought ughhh

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this in SSRS 2005. The rich-textbox was introduced in SSRS 2008 and the only option before this version is multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in SSRS 2005 but in SSRS 2008 and higher below process will work.

You can create multiple placeholders in single cell, set option "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles" in every place holder in which you are using HTML tag.
For Example I'm using two placeholders as shown below:
1st placeholder expression- ="**" & "Bold" & "**" (use html tag for bold text)
2nd placeholder expression ="Normal"
It gives
**Bold** Normal

Comment: Placeholders are not available in SSRS 2005, you are posting qa solution for 2008 but the original question is for ssrs 2005.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in SSRS2005 (yes **2005**, not 2008, etc), is to use a set of textboxes within a rectangle.

I've even managed to achieve this using **carefully** placed textboxes next to each other, with the BOLD being set to specific text boxes.

I found out too that this approach allowed me to determine if the words should be bold or not based on an **Expression** on the Font Bold property. I can even centre the bolded words and not have to centre the other words.

But the trick is to place it all inside a rectangle, make the rectangle the size of all the boxes combined and then drag the rectangle into a Table row cell or place it free-form anywhere else in the report.

It does work, but it's messy.

ps: You can adjust the placement of controls by the **Millimeter**, so be prepared for micro adjustments to get the alignment right.